# Why do dicts compare greater than any int?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, inequality

My code accidentally compared a dict to an int using an inequality and it turns out that any dict evaluates True when tested to be greater than an int.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d > 0
Out[20]: True
d > 10e99999999999999
Out[21]: True
```

Why does this happen instead of a type error?

This happens running on Python 2.7

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to test?

Comment: @toonarmycaptain Really? `python -c "{} > 1"`

Comment: cannot reproduce in python 3

Comment: @Shashwat they removed dictionary magnitude comparisons in Python3

Comment: @toonarmycaptain what are 'dictionary magnitude comparisons"???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in a>b you're comparing the magnitude of a to b, here we're doing it with a dictionary.

Comment: @toonarmycaptain "magnitude" is non-standard terminology, as far as I know. I suppose it comes from mathematics.

Answer (score 8):

From the [Python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> **Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily** (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result).

The [Python 3.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html) has instead this:

> **The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise a TypeError exception** when comparing a complex number with another built-in numeric type, **when the objects are of different types that cannot be compared**, or in other cases where there is no defined ordering.

Meaning what you are seeing is no longer possible as of Python 3, but instead such comparisons yield a `TypeError` like you expected.

Answer (score 3):

First, the Python team agrees with you -- in Python 3, this is an error.

In earlier Python versions everything is comparable with each other, to make it consistent some types always sort before other types.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in Python 2.7 Dictionaries are always greater than integers. Apparently it's alphabetical?